# std::to_string vs stringstream

Tags: c++, c++11, tostring, stringstream

The code below shows 2 solutions (`std::to_string` and `std::stringstream`) that convert an `int` `m_currentSoundTime` to `std::string`. Is `std::to_string` or `std::stringstream` faster?

```
// Compute current sound time in minute and convert to string
stringstream currentTime;
currentTime << m_currentSoundTime / 60;
m_currentSoundTimeInMinute =  currentTime.str();
```

or

```
m_currentSoundTimeInMinute = to_string( m_currentSoundTime / 60 );
```

Comment: What does your profiler tell you?

Comment: As with most implementation-dependent performance questions, the correct answer is "measure and find out". If it's not worth the effort to measure practically, it is probably not worth the effort to optimize.

Comment: "it is probably not worth the effort to optimize": I'd rather say "optimize for readability".

Answer (score 7):

In any reasonable library implementation `to_string` will be *at least* as fast as `stringstream` for this. However, if you wanted to put 10 ints into a string, `stringstream` will likely be faster. If you were to do `to_string(a) + ", " + to_string(b) + /*...*/` every operation would probably cause an allocation and a copy from the previous string to the new allocation - not true with `stringstream`.

More importantly, it's pretty obvious from your example code that `to_string` is cleaner for dealing with converting a *single* int to a string.

Comment: I call bullshit ;) You are forgetting the move semantics in action here. `to_string(a)` returns a temporary, which can be modified by `+ ", "`, which itself returns a temporary... So in fact, it is likely that your chained calls with `to_string` will be faster (no `virtual` dispatch, ...).

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yes but the temporary result from `to_string(a)` likely has a `capacity` _just_ large enough for what it's currently holding. So when you `+ ", "`, even if you don't need an extra `string` temporary, the allocation the current `string` owns needs to be remade to be larger, the old data copied to the new allocation, etc. Repeat for each `+`. The implementation could (should) use `realloc`... but it will have the same problem, inconsistently.

Comment: Actually: the implementation is unlikely to have a strict capacity (more likely, it will contain enough space for the minimum integer); furthermore, `std::string` should use *amortized allocation*. It may, of course, lead to one or two reallocations... but there is no telling whether that will be more than `std::stringstream`, and don't forget that `std::stringstream::str()` will allocate a `string` (if you need to).

Comment: I agree with Mike Seymoure "What does your profiler tell you?". I have profiled this before and David is correct. Use ostringstream for multiple conversions, to_string for a single conversion. The expensive part of a ostringstream is it's construction, it's cheap after that. For a single conversion a to_string will be at least as fast as a ostringstream and less boilerplate.

Answer (score 5):

This [blog post](http://zverovich.net/2013/09/07/integer-to-string-conversion-in-cplusplus.html) tests several int-to-string conversion methods (using GCC 4.7 on Ubuntu 13.04). In this
case `to_string` is somewhat slower than `stringstream`. But this probably depends strongly on the compiler and std library.

Comment: I looked at libc++ implementation of `to_string`, and it just delegates to `snprintf`. Simpler, I guess, but indeed surprising.

Comment: `In this case to_string is somewhat slower than stringstream`. In the blog post `to_string` is faster than `stringstream`. Did I get something wrong here?